# Inserting node in front of Linked List

Tags: c++

The below code is supposed to add a node at the front of a linked list and print the current elements. But running this code gives me run time error and the program terminates. When asking for how many numbers and i typed a number and then it shows "main.cpp has stopped working". What might be wrong ?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

struct Node
{

    int data;
    Node* next;
};
struct Node* head;
using namespace std;
void Insert(int x)
{
        Node* temp=new Node();
        temp->data=x;
        temp->next=head;
        head=temp;


}

void Print()
{
    Node* temp1=head;
    while(temp1!=NULL)
    {
        printf("%d\n",temp1->data);
        temp1=temp1->next;

    }
    printf("\n");
}

int main()
{
    head=NULL;
    printf("how many numbers?\n");
    int n,i,x;
    scanf("%d",n);
    for(i=0;i<n;i++)
    {
        printf("Enter the number: \n");
        scanf("%d",x);
        Insert(x);
        Print();
    }
    return 0;
```

}

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help (‘**why isn't this code working?**’) must include the desired behaviour, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself**. Questions without **a clear problem statement** are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: `scanf("%d", &n);` Note the ampersand.

Comment: On a sidenote: You should learn to clean up - delete the memory you allocated when done.

Comment: Are you sure that this is C++?

Comment: Yes.This is C++, Thanks to Igor. It caused the problem

Comment: Perhaps this will help [->](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/list/list/)

Comment: This is not C++ - Use [this](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/list/list/) to do the business. Also look into ifrsteam,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not even a linked list problem:

```
int n,i,x;
scanf("%d",n);
```

should be

```
int n,i,x;
scanf("%d",&n);
```

(there's another occurrence of that below)

because scanning integers need their address, as opposed to strings.

Comment: BTW forget what I said about your linked list (now edited out), insertion looks okay. Trying to be a smartass needs more testing :)